# node.js console app code to manage Azure Cosmos db tutorial code throwing error as undefined

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm running a node.js console app from the official tutorial in the azure documentation. Please find the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-nodejs-get-started
The code is below:

```
const cosmos = require("@azure/cosmos");
const CosmosClient = cosmos.CosmosClient;
 
const endpoint = "******"; // Add your endpoint
const masterKey = "******"; // Add the masterkey of the endpoint
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, auth: { masterKey } });
const databaseId  = "brondbid"; // Add the Database ID
const containerId  = "broncollectid"; // Add the Container ID

const querySpec = {
    query: "SELECT * FROM c"    
};

async function run() {

    const { result: results } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec, { enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }).toArray();

    for (var queryResult of results) {
        let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
        console.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}\n`);
    }
}

async function handleError(error) {
    console.log("\nAn error with code '" + error.code + "' has occurred:");
    console.log("\t" + error.body || error);
}

run().catch(handleError);
```

When I'm running node app.js at the terminal, I'm getting this error.

```
An error with code 'undefined' has occurred:
        undefined
```

Comment: Can you try by changing `const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, auth: { masterKey } });` to `const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key: masterKey });`?

Comment: Still gave me the same error.

Comment: which line is throwing the erorr? can you add more details on the error

Comment: It's not saying the line, just printing the pre-defined error statement from the code.

Comment: Would like to understand more on this, because the steps provided in documentation should be enough

Comment: @Sajeetharan - the issue is that OP is not following the documentation properly :). I took the code sample from there and was able to run it without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
const cosmos = require("@azure/cosmos");
const CosmosClient = cosmos.CosmosClient;

const endpoint = "******"; // Add your endpoint
const masterKey = "******"; // Add the masterkey of the endpoint
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key: masterKey });
const databaseId  = "brondbid"; // Add the Database ID
const containerId  = "broncollectid"; // Add the Container ID

const querySpec = {
  query: "SELECT * FROM c"
};

async function run() {
  const database = client.database(databaseId);
  const container = database.container(containerId);

  const { resources: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec, { enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }).fetchAll();

  for (var queryResult of results) {
    let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
    console.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}\n`);
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log("\nAn error with code '" + error.code + "' has occurred:");
  console.log("\t" + error.body || error);
}

run().catch(handleError);
```

Essentially your code was failing because there is no `.toArray()` method available on the query result. Since it is not a REST API error, you are getting the `undefined` for error code.

Also, the query returns the data in `resources` key and not `result` key like you are using.

Comment: Wow! it worked. You're right. But shouldn't that be mentioned in the tutorial in the Azure documentation?

Comment: Awesome! I am glad to hear that it worked. It's all there in the documentation. Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#QueryItem.

Comment: I think I was following an old tutorial. I will paste a link when I find it. It's also there in the Azure website I don't know why.

Comment: I see. I believe you were following the tutorial for an older version of SDK.  It used to be like your code in the older version. Please do not bother about finding the link. Just use the link you shared in your question as it makes use of the latest version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, again. I really appreciate your inputs.